# How to check if the particular username exists in the firebase? (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I have tried all of the StackOverflow methods but all the methods are checking if it's null or not.
I wanted to check the particular strings under the "Users" node. example: (aaaaa) (bbbbb) or the child value in it (username : "aaaaa")
if users enter username as "asaaa" or "bbbbb" in registration will be a prompt error. (i want to check all of the values in all of the nodes of firebase)
I have searched all over the stack overflow but most of the solutions need to know the node names in order to run. I want to retrieve all of the names of the nodes under "Users" back to check.
if a user uses "aaaaa" as a username during registration will be setError in the TextInputLayout.

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText username, fullname, email, password;
Button register;
TextView txt_login;
public String strUsername;

FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference reference;
ProgressDialog pd;
private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

private static String users_from_database;
private ArrayList<String> username_list = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    fullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    register = findViewById(R.id.btn_Register);
    txt_login = findViewById(R.id.txt_login);


    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    checkForUsername();

   txt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.show();

            String str_username = username.getText().toString();
            String str_fullname = fullname.getText().toString();
            String str_email = email.getText().toString();
            String str_password = password.getText().toString();

            strUsername = username.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!username_list.contains(strUsername)) {
                // do your job here , suppose send verification code to phone number
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_fullname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email) ||
                        TextUtils.isEmpty(str_password)){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"All fields are required!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                } else if (str_password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Password must be over 6 characters.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                } else {
                    register(str_username,str_fullname,str_email,str_password);
                }
            } else {
                username.setError("Username Exist");
            }



        }
    });
}
private void checkForUsername(){

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                users_from_database = (String) ds.child("username").getValue();

                username_list.add(users_from_database);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String s : username_list) {
                    stringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
                }
                Log.d("ZI", stringBuilder.toString());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("ZI", "Failed");
        }
    });
}

private void register(final String username, final String fullname, String email, String password){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        String userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

                        firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Verification Email Has Been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Email not sent" + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });


          

                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(username);

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("username",username.toLowerCase());
                        hashMap.put("fullname",fullname);
                        hashMap.put("email",email);
                        hashMap.put("password",password);
                        hashMap.put("imageurl","");

                        reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,EmailActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Register Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWOHh.png)

Comment: You can check the documentation example here: [Android developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). By the way, if the user in your application is not registered, he/she has not access to reading data from the database so you could not check for that, maybe you should add a screen that allows for the username selection after the user has logged in /signed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public path `usernames` where you just store the usernames that are already used and are publicly visible. When registering a new user you can check there is a username already exists. Also don't try to get all of then to check if a single one exists. Just call the path `usernames/{username}` and if that is `null` there username doens't exist. Reading all of them would blow up your Firebase bill.

Comment: any example of coding that I can reference with it?

Comment: Just check with `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usernames/aaa")` if there is any data on it in the database.

Comment: if I want to check all of the path names, i will just .getReference("username/") ???

Comment: There is no reason to get all of them. It would just cost you money without any benefit doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by following steps .

1. get all `username` child from your `DatabaseReference` and add it to a ArrayList.
2. Check user provided `username` is available in ArrayList (*from step 1*) or not . If contains then set error , otherwise do your job to complete registration .

Update- I think you are performing button click for registration before executing / finished `checkForUsername();` method. So the `if...else` statement not working properly and its overriding data . It was my mistake . We should perform check all users from database first then perform the next part of registration . So without using `checkForUsername()` method separately in `onCreate()` , we will do everything in button on click . check the code -

```
       register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.show();

            String str_username = username.getText().toString();
            String str_fullname = fullname.getText().toString();
            String str_email = email.getText().toString();
            String str_password = password.getText().toString();

            strUsername = username.getText().toString().trim();


            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/");
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                users_from_database = (String) ds.child("username").getValue();

                username_list.add(users_from_database);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String s : username_list) {
                    stringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
                }
              //  Log.d("ZI", stringBuilder.toString());

                  if (!username_list.contains(strUsername)) {
                    // do your job here , suppose send verification code to phone number
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_fullname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email) ||
                            TextUtils.isEmpty(str_password)) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    } else if (str_password.length() < 6) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password must be over 6 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        register(str_username, str_fullname, str_email, str_password);
                    }
                } else {
                    username.setError("Username Exist");
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("ZI", "Failed");
        }
    });

        }
    });
```

Update- you can check `DataSnapshot` exist or not . If not exist , then you can set test value to start your database . This will execute only one time . You may check -

```
       register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.show();

            String str_username = username.getText().toString();
            String str_fullname = fullname.getText().toString();
            String str_email = email.getText().toString();
            String str_password = password.getText().toString();

            strUsername = username.getText().toString().trim();


            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/");
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> testHash = new HashMap<>();
                        testHash.put("username", "testusername");
                        ref.child("test")
                                .setValue(testHash).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    ref.keepSynced(true);
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("ZI", "Failed ", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {

                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            users_from_database = (String) ds.child("username").getValue();
                            username_list.add(users_from_database);
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for (String s : username_list) {
                                stringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
                            }
                            Log.d("ZI", stringBuilder.toString());

                            if (!username_list.contains(strUsername)) {
                                // do your job here , suppose send verification code to phone number
                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_fullname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email) ||
                                        TextUtils.isEmpty(str_password)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                } else if (str_password.length() < 6) {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password must be over 6 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    register(str_username, str_fullname, str_email, str_password);
                                }
                            } else {
                                username.setError("Username Exist");
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.d("ZI", "Failed");
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesnt work. The data just override the previous data with the same username of it.

Comment: this definitely work , attach your code in question .

Comment: I have uploaded my code. It doesnt work it just overrides the existed username with current data.

Comment: your attched code executing perfectly , whats the problem in your side ?  you should dismiss the `ProgressDialog`  after setError , `username.setError("Username Exist");
                    pd.dismiss();`

Comment: Not working. The progress dialog just keeps on spinning.

Comment: I see , If you have no data in database , this will make conflict . Keep minimum one test username child then try.

Comment: I did have 2 users in the firebase but it didnt work.

Comment: Please attach your latest database picture. If possible share your latest code also.

Comment: If nothing exist , how we could check existence!! path `Users` and child `username` should available in database

Answer (score 0):

> I have searched all over the stack overflow but most of the solutions need to know the node names in order to run.

Even in your example, you can check if a user exists by checking the existence of the following node in the database:

```
root/users/$userName
```

In code should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
DatabaseReference userNameRef = usersRef.child("aaaaa");
userNameRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                String fullName = snapshot.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", fullName);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The user doesn't exist!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

While @TarikHuber answer it will work, please note that in this case, it's not necessary to create an additional node to hold all usernames, since your database structure already does that. So in terms of checking if a user exists:

```
root/users/$userName
```

It's the exact same thing as:

```
root/usernames/$userName
```

Since the nodes in the Realtime Database are represented by pairs of keys and values, please note that the keys are unique. So there is no way you can have duplicate nodes. As each node can be considered a Map.

However, if by chance you can have multiple users in the database sharing the same user name, then you should use a query as in the following lines of code:

```
Query queryByUserName = usersRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo("aaaaa");
queryByUserName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                if(ds.exists()) {
                    String fullName = ds.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", fullName);
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The user doesn't exist!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

According to your screenshot, in both cases, the result in the logcat will be:

```
james
```

P.S. While @ZahidIslam answer might also work, downloading the entire "Users" node and performing the check on the client is not the best option, as it's considered very costly. It's a waste of bandwidth and resources.

**Edit:**

According to you last comment:

> I think u misunderstood me. I want to search thru all the nodes under the rootNodes

There is no way you can create a Query that can search under all nodes inside your database. You can, however, download the entire database and do the filtering on the client, but this is very costly and not recommended.

The best option that you have is to create a separate query for each and every node, but only if all the children have the same fields. Or you can keep the users only in the "Users" node (as you do right now), and the code in my answer will always work perfectly fine.

Comment: DatabaseReference userNameRef = usersRef.child("aaaaa"); Not just "aaaaa" node needed to be checked. the "aaaaa" supposingly should be all of the nodes even "bbbbb", "ccccc" or other randome name will be checked to ensure no nodes are having the same name.

Comment: If a user enters a specific value when registering, for example, "aaaaa" the code in my answer checks if it already exists. If it exists it will print the username, otherwise, it will print an error, as in my updated answer, right?

Comment: Remember that it will check against all records in the "Users" node. Is it ok now?

Comment: but what if the users enters a random value like "cccccc"? does it check if it exists in the database? ((DatabaseReference userNameRef = usersRef.child("aaaaa");)) this only checks for "aaaaa". If any possible answer is that i can turn in into ((DatabaseReference userNameRef = usersRef.child(username); )) but it doesnt work i bet.

Comment: And urm im not checking for the fullName, instead i dont want 2 users to have the same username instead of fullName.

Comment: Yes, this is what this code does. The `fullName` is **only** printed if the user **already** exists. Instead of printing a message like "The users already exist", it's printing the fullName. That's it. Is it clear now?

Comment: DatabaseReference userNameRef = usersRef.child("aaaaa"); Query queryByUserName = usersRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo("aaaaa"); ||||||| But what should I change the "aaaaa" into to check the whole database? Can u try to implement it into my code?

Comment: `.orderByChild("username").equalTo("aaaaa")` is searching in the **entire** "Users" node. So if it finds a user that has the `username` set to "aaaaa" it prints the fullName, otherwise it prints "The user doesn't exist!". Right?

Comment: Ok. I think u misunderstood me. I want to search thru all the nodes under the rootNodes that contain username:"the username input by the user during registration". it is randomly type and I wouldnt know what username does the user typed. (definitely not "aaaaa"). And other than that, I do not want to check if username is exist in the node but instead i want to check the value of the username for each node to see if the specified value of the username is taken or not.

Comment: What you are looking for is **not** possible. So please check my updated answer for more details. The simplest solution would be to keep the users **only** in the "Users" not and check the existence only there.

Comment: Any idea how to do that thing that u mentioned?

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry I always forget to write why I save `usernames` under a different path. Most apps save under users critical data that should not be accessible by public. Also most of the apps that uses uernames requre to enter one before registration. Allowing someone to read `users/${username}` just to check if the username exists would not be so nice. Users maybe also can change usernames. For that a more reasons I generaly always use a seperate collection/list when storing usernames. Sorry for not explaining that more in the answer.